# How to print cv::Mat in any of CSV, C, Python, MatLab, NumPy styles format

Tags: c++, opencv

I have an OpenCV matrix. I want to print it formatted in any style as mentioned in the question.

```
cv::Mat1b image = cv::imread(input_name, cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
std::cout << format_in_c_style(image);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In addition to creating a `cv::Formatter` explicitly, one can also use `cv::format()`, which can be used with `std::cout` directly, and is a little bit shorter:

```
cv::Mat image;    //Loaded from somewhere
std::cout << cv::format(image, "numpy") << std::endl;
```

Where the second argument to `cv::format()` is any of the strings mentioned in [brotherofken](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17040802/1601291)'s answer.

In OpenCV version 3, `format()` no longer takes a string, but an enumeration. The enumeration constants correspond to the allowed string values, and are as follows:

```
FMT_DEFAULT
FMT_MATLAB
FMT_CSV
FMT_PYTHON
FMT_NUMPY
FMT_C
```

The invocation is similar to above:

```
std::cout << cv::format(image, cv::Formatter::FMT_NUMPY) << std::endl;
```

Comment: Thank you! I think it's more convinient way to print data.

Answer (score 6):

You can use undocumented `cv::Formatter` class for this purposes. See example below:

```
cv::Mat1b const image = cv::imread(m_cl_parameters.input_name, cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);

cv::Formatter const * c_formatter(cv::Formatter::get("CSV"));

c_formatter->write(std::cout, image);
```

You should not destroy `cv::Formatter` object obtained from `cv::Formatter::get(...)` after usage.

Function `cv::Formatter::get(const char* fmt)` can deal with following formats:

**"MATLAB"**

Output example:

```
[120, 195, 226;
 142, 138, 78;
 195, 142, 226]
```

**"CSV"** - comma-separated value.

Output example:

```
120, 195, 226
142, 138, 78
195, 142, 226
```

**"PYTHON"**

Output example:

```
[[120, 195, 226],
 [142, 138, 78],
 [195, 142, 226]]
```

**"NUMPY"**

Output example:

```
array([[120, 195, 226],
       [142, 138, 78],
       [195, 142, 226]], type='uint8')
```

**"C"** - produces c-style array

Output example:

```
{120, 195, 226, 142, 138, 78, 195, 142, 226}
```

Comment: Asked and answered at the same time by the same person ;-) Thanks for the hint btw.. +1

Comment: It is standard option on StackOverflow. There are "Answer your own question" checkbox below the "Post your question" button. It's just one of the ways to share knowledge. Thank you :-)