# OpenCV Mat -> Matlab Mat File

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv, data-conversion, mat

I would like to convert my OpenCV Mat to a Matlab .mat file, which can be read easily by Matlab. I don't want to use a Mex function to directly provide the data to matlab, since I want to save the data on the hard disk.

There is the cvmatio cpp function available: [cvmatio](https://github.com/hbristow/cvmatio), but as I have seen there is only a function to read a matlab Mat with OpenCV, but no function to create a matlab Mat out of openCV.

Another possibility is to store it as csv file and read it then via matlab, as mentioned here: [OpenCV -> CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27704711/4767895)

Is there any other library or function available, which converts the data directly to an Matlab mat?

Answer (score 3):

I have found this as the best answer for the question, since I haven't found a direct way without the use of a temporary file.

Write the OpenCV Mat to a CSV File:

```
#include <fstream>
void MeasureTool::writeCSV(string filename, cv::Mat m) 
{
   cv::Formatter const * c_formatter(cv::Formatter::get("CSV"));
   ofstream myfile;
   myfile.open(filename.c_str());
   c_formatter->write(myfile, m);
   myfile.close();
}
```

[Source for write CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17040802/4767895)

And in Matlab use the following function to read the csv file:

```
x1 = csvread('yourFile.csv',0,0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the following C code for a project some time ago. It;s a little dated but it worked with matlab 2011a. It should serve as an example if nothing else. It does make a number of assumptions - mostly documented.

Input parameters are the filename to write to, an array of pointers to CvMat, an array of names for these matrices and the number of matrices to write.

```
void writeMatFile( const char *fileName, CvMat ** matrices, const char **names, int numMatrices ) {
    FILE *file = fopen( fileName, "wb" );

    for( int i=0; i<numMatrices; i++ ) {
        CvMat * mat = matrices[i];
        const char *name = names[i];

        // If mat is ND we write multiple copies with _n suffixes
        int depth = CV_MAT_CN(mat->type);
        for( int d=0; d<depth; d++ ) {

            // Assumption that we are always dealing with double precision
            uint32_t MOPT = 0000;
            fwrite(&MOPT, 1, sizeof( uint32_t), file);
            uint32_t    mrows = mat->rows;
            uint32_t    ncols = mat->cols;
            uint32_t    imagef = 0;

            char nameBuff[ strlen( name ) + 10];
            strcpy(nameBuff, name);
            if( depth>1) {
                char suffix[5];
                sprintf(suffix, "_L%d", d+1);
                strcat(nameBuff, suffix);
            }

            uint32_t    nameLength = strlen( nameBuff ) + 1;
            fwrite( &mrows, 1, sizeof( uint32_t), file);
            fwrite( &ncols, 1, sizeof( uint32_t), file);
            fwrite( &imagef, 1, sizeof( uint32_t), file);
            fwrite( &nameLength, 1, sizeof( uint32_t), file);
            fwrite( nameBuff, nameLength, 1, file );

            for( int col = 0; col<ncols; col++ ) {
                for( int row=0; row<mrows; row++ ) {
                    CvScalar sc = cvGet2D(mat, row, col);
                    fwrite(&(sc.val[d]), 1, sizeof( double ), file);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    fclose( file );
}
```